# Embed Nextcloud app: Collabora in Node-Express website?

Tags: html, node.js, express, host, nextcloud

### Scenario

After having built a basic website in the node-express framework at `http://localhost:3000` and hosting collabora via nextcloud in docker at `http://<my ip-adress>/8080/s/<some document share link>/`, I noticed that I am not yet able to embed the nextcloud app collabora by entering:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://<my ip-adress>:8080/s/some document share link">
        </iframe>
```

in the `render` of `app.js`.

Additionally I was not able to find many instructions on how to embed the nextcloud application in a website.

### Question

Hence I had the following question: "How can I embed `.ods` editor collabora via nextcloud on my website built with node using the express framework hosted via docker on a Windows 10 desktop?

### Error message:

> < my ip-adress > has redirected you too often.